# Accessing IPMI address

Tags: virtual-machines, xenserver, ipmi, bmc

Currently if I want to know the server IPMI address, I will have to go to the SBIOS and check under BMC. 
Is there a way to get the IPMI address from inside a virtual machine ?

Comment: Please specify the vendor of your BMC / motherboard.

Comment: And please tell us, why do you want to look for BMC settings from virtual machine, not from physically installed OS?

Comment: If not from a virtual machine then is it possible to know the IPMI address from a physically installed OS? If yes, then how?

Comment: Vendors : SMC , Gigabyte

Comment: + Cirrascale (Maximum nos)

Answer (score 3):

To get information about IPMI (and change it's settings) from a physically installed OS, you could use [ipmitool(1)](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/ipmitool) and numerous software like it. Mostly it requires root privileges to run.

Then you could do something like that:

```
$ sudo ipmitool lan print
Set in Progress         : Set Complete
Auth Type Support       : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD OEM 
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD OEM 
                        : User     : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD OEM 
                        : Operator : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD OEM 
                        : Admin    : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD OEM 
                        : OEM      : 
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 172.20.0.30
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.255.0
MAC Address             : 00:25:90:9d:a1:dc
SNMP Community String   : AMI
IP Header               : TTL=0x40 Flags=0x40 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x10
BMC ARP Control         : ARP Responses Enabled, Gratuitous ARP Disabled
Gratituous ARP Intrvl   : 0.0 seconds
Default Gateway IP      : 172.20.0.1
Default Gateway MAC     : 00:00:00:00:00:00
Backup Gateway IP       : 0.0.0.0
Backup Gateway MAC      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
802.1q VLAN ID          : Disabled
802.1q VLAN Priority    : 0
RMCP+ Cipher Suites     : 0,1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12
Cipher Suite Priv Max   : XaaaXXaaaXXaaXX
                        :     X=Cipher Suite Unused
                        :     c=CALLBACK
                        :     u=USER
                        :     o=OPERATOR
                        :     a=ADMIN
                        :     O=OEM
```

In this example 172.20.0.30 is address of IPMI.